# keeping jquery dialog box to be opened after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dialog

Im a beginner in jquery.

I have an ASP.net page that has:

A dialog box that contains user control
the user control do postback on hidden field

in this postback, dialog is closed automatically
but,  I need to keep dialog to be opened with the same state

Anyone can help me?

Comment: can you post your code samples?

Answer (score 0):

well i don't have knowledge of ASP but i tell you the logic behind this,

simply just set a extra parameter in url like `domain.com/index.php?dialog=y`

check open your dialog to check this param, i show you with php like this..

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['dialog']) && $_GET['dialog'] == 'y') { ?>
// your jquery dialog here to open on page load
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET you can make use of the `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock`. [Read about it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx)
This allows you to output some javascript to the page, so after your page has postback, you can call this to output javascript which opens the dialog back up.

e.g.

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page.GetType(), "js", "openDialog();", true);
```

Alternatively, what I do, is to just create a public string variable on the page

```
public string _JS;
```

Then on your .aspx page you can just have this within your script tags.

```
<script>
    $(function() { <%=(this._JS)%> });
</script>
```

I am using jQuery here in the example, but when the page loads, anything that you put within `_JS` will run.

```
_JS = "alert('hello world');";
```

Answer (score 0):

write this code in script tag on that page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      //write code to show popup

});
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function() {
   //write code to show popup
};
```

It will help you out.